# BASH:Passing arguments from one shebang to another

Tags: bash, shell

I have two scripts.

temp.sh

```
#! /usr/bin/foo
echo "$@"
```

foo

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
source "$@"
```

This works  except in the following case when temp.sh has a parameter in its shebang as follows.

temp.sh

```
#! /usr/bin/foo -x
echo "$@"
```

This makes it problematic.

```
/root/foo: line 4: source: -x: invalid option
source: usage: source filename [arguments]
```

Is there anyway I can pass this -x(or for that matter any and all parameters) passed to temp.sh's shebang to foo's shebang?

Comment: Could you be more specific than "breaks things"? BTW, the lack of space between the `echo` and the `"$@"` is, for example, one way for things to become broken. If you showed the exact error, we'd have a better idea of whether that was a typo on the question entry or the cause of the issue you're asking about.

Comment: (BTW, consider `printf '%q ' "$@"; echo` instead of `echo "$@"`; the latter doesn't give you any way to distinguish the difference between `./yourscript "hello world"` and `./yourscript "hello" "world"`, despite those being very different commands).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the printf tip..  i edited my question..

Comment: Why do you expect behavior different than what you're getting? `"$@"` refers to the full list of arguments, `-x` is an argument, so you're passing it to `source`, which doesn't expect or accept it.

Comment: `bash -x scriptname` works because the `-x` is *before* the script; but what you're running here invokes `bash scriptname -x`, so the `-x` is an argument to the script, not the shell interpreter. If you want to write your script such that it explicitly recognizes such arguments you can do so, but that's what it'll take.

Comment: Thats why i said its problematic... and hence my question.

Comment: So, what's the question? What you can put in the script to recognize `-x` and kin, and pass them to the shell? That's easy enough.

Comment: Well yeah.. but I'm not sure if every thing passed an argument to the shebang can also be done using `set`

Comment: All of the relevant ones can; things like `-c` or `-s` don't make any sense when running a script by name, and using `bash -l` for a script is evil (makes that script intrinsically nonportable, even to other user accounts on the same machine). The list of exceptions to the "it's all `set`-accessible" rule is up at the very top of `man bash`.

Comment: There's also +- o "attribute to set" as well as the --options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to consume the first argument and pass it to the shell interpreter when it matches a specific set of patterns, you can do that yourself:

```
# treat first argument of -x or -v as intended for the shell interpreter
case $1 in -[xv]) set "$1"; shift;; esac

source "$@"
```

Comment: I guess I just have to handle each option as mentioned in man bash.  Also my source shows up in the trace when using -x.. Anyway i can hide that ?? :)